# SetCurSel for unsorted CComboBox not working

Tags: mfc

When setting Sort=false in the CComboBox properties editor the following does not work (the item selected is the first: index=0):

```
SetCurSel(2)
SelectString(0, "2")
SetWindowText("2")
```

It will work if sort=true but then the list of items may look so:

```
1
10
2
20
5
50
```

Example (selection will be "1" in all three controls):

```
BOOL CMyDialog::OnInitDialog()
{
    ((CComboBox*)GetDlgItem(IDC_CB_a))->AddString("1");
    ((CComboBox*)GetDlgItem(IDC_CB_a))->AddString("2");
    ((CComboBox*)GetDlgItem(IDC_CB_a))->AddString("3");
    ((CComboBox*)GetDlgItem(IDC_CB_a))->SelectString(0, "3");

    ((CComboBox*)GetDlgItem(IDC_CB_b))->AddString("1");
    ((CComboBox*)GetDlgItem(IDC_CB_b))->AddString("2");
    ((CComboBox*)GetDlgItem(IDC_CB_b))->AddString("3");
    ((CComboBox*)GetDlgItem(IDC_CB_b))->SetCurSel(2);

    ((CComboBox*)GetDlgItem(IDC_CB_c))->AddString("1");
    ((CComboBox*)GetDlgItem(IDC_CB_c))->AddString("2");
    ((CComboBox*)GetDlgItem(IDC_CB_c))->AddString("3");
    ((CComboBox*)GetDlgItem(IDC_CB_c))->SetWindowText("3");

    return CMyBaseDialog::OnInitDialog();
}
```

Reminder: This WORKS when Combo is sorted.

Comment: What happens? What is the return value? What do you expect to happen, when you call SetWindowText?

Comment: As stated the item selected is the first: index=0. Same result for all three methods

Comment: Where is the CComboBox? In a dialog for which you have a class derived from CDialog? In which function/upon which trigger do you SetCurSel?

Comment: Are you calling one of the functions per test? Or are you calling all three functions in one test?

Comment: @Werner - Yes a class derived from CDialog, OnInitDialog. Just one function at a time.

Comment: Before or after you call CDialog::OnInitDialog? Are you also using DDX (DoDataExchange)?

Comment: Before and not using DDX

Comment: Your code works fine here. You need to check that there is no code that changes back the selection.

Comment: And the style CBS_HASSTRINGS is set too?

Comment: Try calling `CMyBaseDialog::OnInitDialog()` before accessing the dialog items